# magento video testimonial extension setup and configuration

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Using Magento Community version 1.7.0.2.
Downloaded Video Testimonials: [aw_vidtest-1.3.0.community_edition](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/video-testimonials.html)

I just downloaded and installed this extension. Followed instructions as recommended [on this page](http://doc.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/AW_Vidtest-1.3/readme.html) from extension creator aHead Works. But once on the **Registering on youtube.com** step on the **Catalog > Video Testimonials > Settings** I received a 404 Error. The other two options "All video" and "Pending video" work fine, the grids are displaying.

Checked that the files where correctly copied and everything is on its place. Any advice?

Comment: Since this is a commercial extension, did you already ask their customer support?

Comment: Yes, I already asked on their related forum to this extension. It's a commercial extension indeed but, as long as I understand, they only provide support to payed suscribers. That's why I'm asking here too, SO is a great source and many times I get quicker answers here than on other supports forums, even without asking as the question was already made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself. As many other issues with Magento, just needed to logout/login.

Comment: There is another one for adding images and videos in Magento product and CMS pages. http://www.fmeextensions.com/media-gallery.html